# SWI-Prolog partition predicate works differently in REPL than in programme

Tags: prolog, quicksort, higher-order-functions

I imlemented quicksort using [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org) this way:

```
qsort([],[]).
qsort([H|T],S) :-
  partition([X,O]>>compare(O,X,H),T,L,E,G),
  qsort(L,A),
  qsort(G,Z),
  append([A,[H|E],Z],S).

main :-
  length(L,22),
  maplist(random(0,9),L),
  qsort(L,S),
  maplist(writeln,[L,S]).
```

It doesn't work correctly. The input and output lists are the same. However when I run this in the REPL there on the right:
`length(S,22), maplist(random(0,9),S),[H|T]=S, partition([X,O]>>compare(O,X,H),T,L,E,G).`

the random lists do get sorted. Whence the difference?

Comment: I added a note to end of the page [library(yall)](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall) at SWI Prolog documentation, but it shows up only at https://eu.swi-prolog.org/ not https://www.swi-prolog.org (for now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the second clause for the `qsort/2` predicate is compiled, there's no information on `H` other than it's a variable when compiling the lambda expression. Any variable occurring in the lambda expression that's not find in a local lambda parameter must be declared using the `{}/1` construct. But when running your query at the top-level interpreter, by the time the lambda expression is interpreted, `H` is bound and thus no longer a variable (making the use of the `{}/1` construct unnecessary).

Note that there are several details here at play that are out of scope of the lambda library itself: (1) is the compiler recognizing at compile time that you're calling a meta-predicate with an argument that's a lambda expression? (2) how's a top-level query interpreted? Is the full query first fully compiled or is it meta-interpreted? These details depend on the system itself.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I add `{H}/` in front of `[X,O]>>compare(O,X,H)`. Might be a bug that toplevel doesn't require (but allows) it for the expected behaviour. But I'm not sure, so answers welcome from those in the know.

Comment: Paulo Moura knows!